# iOS in-app purchase always returns SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed and app crashes with no error in log

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have implemented in-app purchase and it used to work till now. I have added a few new in-app purchases and tested. It always switches to SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed and app crashes at that stage and no error message is given. Here is code for in app-purchase:

```
-(void)fetchAvailableProducts{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet
                                 setWithObjects:@"xxx.template8",nil];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                       initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}
- (void)purchaseMyProduct:(SKProduct*)product{
    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                  @"Purchases are disabled in your device" message:nil delegate:
                                  self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
-(IBAction)purchase:(id)sender{
    [self purchaseMyProduct:[validProducts objectAtIndex:0]];
    purchaseButton.enabled = NO;
}

#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"Purchasing");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                     isEqualToString:@"xxx.template8"]) {
                    NSLog(@"Purchased ");
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                              @"Purchase is completed succesfully" message:nil delegate:
                                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alertView show];
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
                //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                //break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    NSInteger count = [response.products count];
    if (count>0) {
        validProducts = response.products;
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([validProduct.productIdentifier
             isEqualToString:@"xxx.template8"]) {
            [productTitleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"Product Title: %@",validProduct.localizedTitle]];
            [productDescriptionLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                              @"Product Desc: %@",validProduct.localizedDescription]];
            [productPriceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                        @"Product Price: %@",validProduct.price]];
        }
    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Not Available"
                            message:@"No products to purchase"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];
    }    
    [activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    purchaseButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: When you say it crashes and no error is given, what do you mean? What do you get for a stack trace?

Comment: Do you have exception breakpoints turned on? I speculate your code is attempting to improperly process/display nil values because of some variable that's previously been valid (in the success case) is not. Look into what you do _after_ the purchase completion -- it's probably either UI updates or invoking some behavior based on what was just purchased.

Comment: I have not changed a thing, but damn it, today everything magically works. Well, I did update Xcode though. But @llario did help me to show error type and I accept the answer. Thank you very much everyone who made an input into this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is a way to check which error occurred on SKPaymentTransaction, you can do:

```
...
case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
    [self failedTransaction:transaction];
...


- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

apply this code and tell us what the log says

**EDIT**:

since the log says that the product identifier is null check in method

```
- (void)purchaseMyProduct:(SKProduct*)product{

 NSLog(@"product id = %@",product.productIdentifier);
```

Comment: product id of transaction is null

Comment: @sermilion you're trying with iOS simulator ? or on  device?

Comment: @sermilion see my edit, oh maybe you not wait that the app fetch all in-app purchase?

Comment: it shows correct product id, and completes purchase (even though, second time, which should not happen i guess), but still freezes at the end, like there is a break point, but there is non...

Comment: @sermilion try to remove the uialertview from skpaymenttransactionstate